# Xamarin Secure Background Screen Preview not support Android version below 8.0

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I try in MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
    base.OnResume();
}

protected override void OnPause()
{
    Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
    base.OnPause();
}
```

However, on Android less than 8.0, the application did not as expected.
Please help me make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided does not trigger the `OnPause` method to set the Flags when you press the App Overview button. My test device has 3-button navigation: Three buttons for Home, Back, and App Overview. The `OnPause` method triggered when you press the Home button.

I could set the Flags in OnCreate method after Xamarin.Forms has loaded. I tested on Android 6.0. It works.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        LoadApplication(new App());

       Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I also tried following your code on Nexus 4 Android 6.0. and it still doesn't work

Comment: I tested with the emulator. Have you try to reinstall the app to check again?